# How to improve error responses when using @RepositoryRestResource

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

I'm using spring's `@RepositoryRestResource` annotation on a `PagingAndSortingRepository`.

When I send an erroneous payload to the corresponding endpoint, the error responses that are sent back are hard to parse, e.g.

```
{
  "cause": {
    "cause": {
      "cause": null,
      "message": "ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint \"uk_bawli8xm92f30ei6x9p3h8eju\"\n  Detail: Key (email)=(jhunstone0@netlog.com) already exists."
    },
    "message": "could not execute statement"
  },
  "message": "could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [uk_bawli8xm92f30ei6x9p3h8eju]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement"
}
```

Is there any way to configure the messages, so it is clear which field (here: email) caused the error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding the error handling - you can implement a [custom exception handler](https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc#using-controlleradvice-classes) for such exceptions, extract the constraint name from the root cause, analyze it and create a corresponding message for the user.

Some error handling examples: [1](https://www.toptal.com/java/spring-boot-rest-api-error-handling), [2](https://github.com/Cepr0/single-file-app).

**UPDATED**

You should check the app log to determine which exception you have to handle. If I'm not mistaken for constraint violation we must handle `org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException`, for example:

```java
@ControllerAdvice
public class CommonExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

  @ExceptionHandler(DataIntegrityViolationException.class)
  ResponseEntity<?> handleDataIntegrityViolation(DataIntegrityViolationException ex, HttpServletRequest req) {

        String causeMessage = NestedExceptionUtils.getMostSpecificCause(ex).getMessage(); // determine the root cause message

        String reqPath = req.getServletPath(); // get the request path            

        String userMessage = ... // Decide what the message you will show to users

        HttpStatus status = HttpStatus... // Decide what the status your response will be have, for example HttpStatus.CONFLICT

        ApiErrorMessage message = new ApiErrorMessage(userMessage, status, reqPath); // Create your custom error message

        return new ResponseEntity<>(message, status); // return response to users
    }

    // other handlers
}
```

Or you can implement this handler easier as in the official [example](https://github.com/paulc4/mvc-exceptions/blob/43cc9c093be5b2ea70f27f5e5f3388cd97cc286d/src/main/java/demo2/web/GlobalExceptionHandlingControllerAdvice.java#L46).

Comment: Can you point me to where in those examples the exact field that caused the error is determined? I see it in the written text of the blog post but can't find it in the given code.

Comment: @cbo in the first example of the first [link](https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc#using-controlleradvice-classes). I updated the answer...