# Spring JPA-Repository with bean validation: Poor error response

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, spring-rest

I'm using a model object like this:

```
@Entity
public class Address {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 20)
    private String location;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "address")
    private Person person;
}
```

with a repository

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "address", path = "address")
public interface AddressRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Address, Long> {

}
```

When I try to post a object that voilates the bean constraints I get a poor error response:

> {"timestamp":"2018-10-05T14:48:23.667+0000","status":500,"error":"Internal
>   Server Error","message":"Could not commit JPA transaction; nested
>   exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while
>   committing the transaction","path":"/address"}

How can I get a usefull error message without implementing every rest controller by myself?

Comment: Is it really important to use annotation `RepositoryRestResource` ?

Comment: Just wanted to reduce boilerplate code

Comment: Try removing that annotation.

Comment: Look at this question and an answer- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50273906/how-to-improve-error-responses-when-using-repositoryrestresource

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define Controller advice to handle exceptions globally and return your custom message as string or `ErrorResponse` object (where you can define your own properties).

```
@RestControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(RollbackException.class)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
    @ResponseBody
    public String handleRollbackException(RollbackException ex) {

        String errorMessage = "Your custom message";
        return errorMessage ;
    }

}
```